# How to inject (add via JavaScript) an anchor text and normal text in a cookie banner from Cookiebot (external JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, cookies, anchor, external, getelementbyid

```
<script>
document.getElementById("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText").innerHTML += ' | <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>'
</script>
```

I've tried this code with the console of Google Chrome. I succeeded. But if I copy and paste it in the area "JavaScript (Footer)" or "JavaScript (Header)" (Here is the external JavaScript file.) then it shows me "(index):208 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" (possible problems: Make a declaration like !important [And where in a code of JavaScript?]? time to load the cookie banner [time difference]). Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML/JS which you have so far? Any way, your code to update DOM element must be triggered once the DOM is ready (or) copy the JS just above `</body>` tag.

Comment: Well **Cannot read property 'innerHTML'** means it could not find the element in your selector or does have `innerHTML`. What do you mean copy/paste it into "JavaScript (Footer)" or "JavaScript (Header)"? Are you trying to run this script to a page you do not have access to hence "injecting"? I'm confused to if you own/have access to the page you are trying to run the script on... Also maybe try place your script into a a dom ready function to ensure the page has loaded before executing selectors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element probably doesn't exist when your Javascript is executing, which is why you're getting the error.

The error tells you that it 'Cannot read the innerHTML of null', which means `document.getElementById("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText")` is returning `null`.

You need to wait for `#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText` to exist, then grab it and update it.

If the `#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText` is available immediately when your page is loaded, just move your JS to the end of the `<body>` element. Otherwise you'll need to set a poll function to wait for it, like:

```
function waitFor(element, f) {
    if (document.querySelector(element)) {
        f();
    } else {
        waitFor(element, f);
    }
}

waitFor('#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText', function() {
    document.getElementById("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText").innerHTML += ' | <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>'
})
```

Comment: Or simply use an event listener like `window.onload=function(){}`. Well... for those who like to keep scripts in the `<head>` tag rather than having scripts mixed in with the html content or at the bottom of the `<body>`

Comment: that won't necessarily work if the element in question is loaded asynchronously, because it could come in after the page has already loaded.

Comment: So your suggestion of putting the script at the bottom of the `body` wouldn't work either.... Using a DOM ready function would mean the page has loaded just the same as placing your script after the element/bottom of the page... If the element is dynamically created then both my suggestion and yours wouldn't work. If anything maybe set an interval to check the element exists and loop until found, once found clear the interval and execute the rest of the source code. By telling me I am wrong you have just removed any/all advantage of your own suggestion.

Comment: @NewToJS that was the first suggestion I made, but I offered a polling function as an alternative for dynamically added elements. Like, try this first, but based on your question it sounds like it won't work, so try this less desirable method if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CookiebotCallback_OnDialogInit() callback, which is executed when Cookiebot is inserted to the DOM, but before the banner displays. You could use that:

```
function CookiebotCallback_OnDialogInit()
{
    document.getElementById("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentText").innerHTML += ' | <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>'   
}
```